Error: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useActionState) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
I am following the example for useActionState found here. I am using nextjs and typescript.
app/page.tsx:
"use client";

import { useActionState } from "react";
import { createUser } from "../components/actions";

const initialState = {
  message: "",
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, formAction] = useActionState(createUser, initialState);

  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required />
      {/* ... */}
      <p aria-live="polite" className="sr-only">
        {state?.message}
      </p>
      <button>Sign up</button>
    </form>
  );
}

../components/actions.ts:
'use server'
 
export default async function createUser(prevState: any, formData: FormData) {
  return {
    message: 'Please enter a valid email',
  }
}

When I run the example, I get:
Error: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useActionState) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
My package.json looks like:
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "db:migrate": "TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{ \"module\": \"commonjs\" }' knex migrate:latest",
    "db:migrate:undo": "TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{ \"module\": \"commonjs\" }' knex migrate:down",
    "db:migrate:make": "TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{ \"module\": \"commonjs\" }' knex migrate:make"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "canary",
    "react-dom": "canary",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "main": "/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {}
}


My tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


Use a canary build of next. It is definitely in v14.3.0-canary.47. So you can do npx create-next-app@14.3.0-canary.47. That's all.

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78445866/258174

Seems to work ;). Can you please create an answer so I can accept it?

Next.js added support for React 19 features, specifically useActionState in PR 65058. The create-next-app template added the same support in PR 65478. Versions 14.3.0-canary.45 and 14.3.0-canary.46, respectively.
Thus you can get support for useActionState in Next.js by running npx create-next-app@14.3.0-canary.46, or any greater version.

You can use the useFormState hook from the react-dom package as a temporary solution instead of the useActionState hook from the react package until a future Next.js update is available.
First, replace the import statement for useActionState with useFormState:
// import { useActionState } from 'react';
import { useFormState } from 'react-dom';
